# Adding addresses to table from Geocoding Google-Api in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make Parent's Control system which allows parent to follow his child location history in WebService.

I have mobile app which sends locations to Realtime Database in Google Firebase. This locations (latitude and longitude) are sent from Firebase to my Javascript code where I want to put them to a table in my HTML. I don't want to put to table longitude and latitude but instead of it I want save addresses based on this locations. That's why I used Google Geolocations API. The problem is, when I set this addresses in the variable I want put into a table, this variable appears to be undefined. I think it can be problem with a scope of this variable but I can't manage with that. Thanks in advance for your help. I put my JS code below:

```
var longitude;
var latitude;
var address;

//GETING DATA FROM FIREBASE
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("locations");
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
        time = snap.child("time").val();
        longitude = snap.child("longitude").val();
        latitude = snap.child("latitude").val();

        latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
        longitude = parseFloat(longitude);

        //CONVERTING LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE INTO ADDRESS

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': location}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address = results[0].formatted_address;
                //HERE ADDRESS IS DISPLAYING GOOD
            }
        });

        //PUT ADDRESS INTO TABLE (THERE IS PROBLEM - ADDRESS IS Undefined)

        $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + address + "</td><td>");
    })
})
```

Comment: It looks like a scoping issue. I think the variable `address` is declared inside a function, so it won't be available outside of that function. Something like `my_address = geocoder.geocode( ....`, where you include `return address` inside the function will allow you to use the variable outside the function

Comment: You could also execute that jQuery append line inside the function where it will have access to the `address` variable

Comment: I declared address variable as global variable in the very beginning of my JS code and inside a function it is local.

Comment: I noticed one more strange thing. When the mobile app is running and new locations are being sent, everything works good and addresses are saving into the table but after refreshing page on my browser it's undefined...

Comment: You can have global and local scoped variable with the same name, but the way you have them declared _should_ reassign it at the global scope. I'm curious if it's some sort of race condition where the jQuery executes _before_ the geocode function. I might recommend trying to execute the jQuery inside the geocode function and see if that helps

Comment: I tried this way but there is another problem. When I put my JQuery append inside conditional expression, in every row time, variable is exactly the same and it is equal to recently received time...

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `jQuery.append()` inside the conditional expression:

```
coder.geocode({'latLng': location}, function (results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var tempAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + tempAddress + "</td><td>");
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this way but there is another problem. When I put my JQuery append inside conditional expression, in every row time, variable is exactly the same and it is equal to recently received time...

Comment: It might work if you use a temporary local variable instead. See updated code in the answer above

Comment: It still doesn't work :/ Every time variable is the same ;/

Comment: Ok you might try an array of addresses. Push each new value into the array and then render the table by iterating through the array. It may be that the data is overwritten when the page refreshes, in which case you can keep the array in localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoder is asynchronous.  You need to use the data in the callback function when/where it is available.  If you want variables from loop in the callback routine, you need to capture them with function closure:

```
var longitude;
var latitude;
var address;

//GETING DATA FROM FIREBASE
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("locations");
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
      time = item.time;
      longitude = item.longitude;
      latitude = item.latitude;

      latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
      longitude = parseFloat(longitude);

      //CONVERTING LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE INTO ADDRESS

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': location
      }, (function(time) {  // function closure on the "time" variable
        return function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          address = results[0].formatted_address;
          //HERE ADDRESS IS DISPLAYING GOOD
          //PUT ADDRESS INTO TABLE (THERE IS PROBLEM - ADDRESS IS Undefined)
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + address + "</td><td>");
        }
      }}(time)));
    })
  })
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c5yhxaur/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var testData = [{
    time: "2019-01-01 12:00:00",
    latitude: 40.7484405,
    longitude: -73.9856644
  },
  {
    time: "2019-01-01 12:10:00",
    latitude: 40.6892494,
    longitude: -74.0445004
  }
]

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var longitude;
  var latitude;
  var address;

  //GETING DATA FROM FIREBASE
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    testData.forEach(function(item, i) {
      time = item.time;
      longitude = item.longitude;
      latitude = item.latitude;

      latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
      longitude = parseFloat(longitude);

      //CONVERTING LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE INTO ADDRESS

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': location
      }, (function(time) {
        return function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          address = results[0].formatted_address;
          //HERE ADDRESS IS DISPLAYING GOOD
          //PUT ADDRESS INTO TABLE (THERE IS PROBLEM - ADDRESS IS Undefined)
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + address + "</td><td>");
        }
      }}(time)));
    })
  })
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="table">
  <table id="table_body">
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```